# How do I open a program from the system tray via .bat

Tags: windows-10, batch, notification-area

I'm trying to retrieve an already running program from the system tray. Using the cursor, it would open when double-clicked. I would like to use a .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be doable using native batch file commands without calling other applications and adding additional complexity (assuming there are command line tools that offer the functionality.) You may be able to achieve this using Powershell (assuming the OS on which you want to run it has Powershell installed and the correct execution policy is enabled.)

You could do it using an AutoIT or AutoHotKey script as both have support for this type of functionality and you could map the script a key combination if desired.

As your preference appears to be for something native to the OS, Powershell may be the way forward.